# Changing Font _Without_ Changing Weight (Bold)

Tags: fonts, bold, boldmath

I feel like this question has probably already been asked, but I cannot find it...

I am using the default `article` class.
I want to create a macro `\ab` which does the following: it simply prints "ab" in *upright, Roman font* in `math mode`. However, I want to be able to use this in settings where the current font is Sans Serif (`\sffamily`) *and/or* where the font is bold (using `\bfseries \boldmath`).

Just writing `\newcommand{\ab}{\textup{ab}}` does *almost* all of this: the only issue is that it obviously doesn't do anything with the font; so it's sometimes Sans Serif. I don't know how to change the font other than `\normalfont` or `\textnormal`, but these both destroy any bold information. So if I do `\newcommand{\ab}{\textnormal{ab}}` then I never get bold.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please add a minimal example of code showing your font setup.

Comment: `\mathrm{ab}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that works, thank you :) -- I thought that was one of the first things I tried, but obviously not! (as evidenced by my forgetting to include it in the question text above). If you want to make an answer, I'll accept; otherwise I'll make one citing your comment :) -- whichever you prefer. I remember being surprised that `\textrm` didn't work (I must have been doing something wrong). Sorry to have posted such a trivial question!

Comment: Ah, I see, it _doesn't_ remove _italics_ (which is, of course, not what I was asking). I think I accidentally tested it with _italics_, rather than **bold**. Thanks again, and sorry again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\mathrm{ab}` will give the math Roman font (and math Roman bold font in `\boldmath`) note that isn't by default Times Roman, but you can chose a Times Roman clone style for your document with for example `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I actually had forgotten that the default font wasn't times, but a different Roman font!